# React: Updating state, mapping over state to display a list but the list disappears from the view after a second?

Tags: reactjs

So i'm trying to learn about state in react and i'm doing a little project. I've got three inputs which each update a value in my state on submit. On submit it then creates an object from those updated state values which it adds to an array in the state.

I then map over the array to display a list of the objects. Problem is when i add a new object on submit the map displays that object for a brief second in the browser and then it returns the state to its default values and displays none of the object entries.

code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names: [],
      id: 1,
      firstName: '',
      secondName: '',
      userName: '',
      gamesPlayed: 0
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    // console.log(this.state.firstName)
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newNames = [...prevState.names, {id: prevState.id, firstName: prevState.firstName,
        secondName: prevState.secondName, userName: prevState.userName, gamesPlayed: prevState.gamesPlayed}]
      const newId = prevState.id += 1
      return ({
        names: newNames,
        id: newId
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
        </header>
        <h2>Add New User</h2>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='First Name'
              name='firstName'
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Last Name'
              name='secondName'
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Username'
              name='userName'
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type='submit'
              value='Submit'
            />
          </form>
          <h2>Users</h2>
          <div>{this.state.names.map((name) => (
            <li key={name.id}>
              <ol>
                {name.firstName} {name.secondName} {name.userName} has played {name.gamesPlayed} games!
              </ol>
            </li>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your form will perform HTTP request to the current URL (will trigger reload page). You can opt to prevent this default behaviour via `preventDefault`

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

```
<form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
```

Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#form-submission

Answer (score 0):

Prevent default form submit replace code line with the below code:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names: [],
      id: 1,
      firstName: '',
      secondName: '',
      userName: '',
      gamesPlayed: 0
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    // console.log(this.state.firstName)
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newNames = [...prevState.names, {id: prevState.id, firstName: prevState.firstName,
        secondName: prevState.secondName, userName: prevState.userName, gamesPlayed: prevState.gamesPlayed}]
      const newId = prevState.id += 1
      return ({
        names: newNames,
        id: newId
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
        </header>
        <h2>Add New User</h2>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='First Name'
              name='firstName'
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Last Name'
              name='secondName'
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Username'
              name='userName'
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <input
              type='submit'
              value='Submit'
            />
          </form>
          <h2>Users</h2>
          <div>{this.state.names.map((name) => (
            <li key={name.id}>
              <ol>
                {name.firstName} {name.secondName} {name.userName} has played {name.gamesPlayed} games!
              </ol>
            </li>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```